Aplicacion con escaner QR falla al iniciar la camara
estoy usando Java en Android Studio para desarrollar una aplicación que permita escanear QR a manera de practica, y he creado mi proyecto para Android 5.0 Lollipop, porque es el mismo que el teléfono que tengo a la mano para probar las aplicaciones que estaba haciendo, lo se, es un teléfono algo viejo.
Los tutoriales que encontré decían que usara la librería de ZXing para crear o escanear los códigos generados, crear los códigos funciona sin problemas pero cuando paso a la parte de usar la cámara, la aplicación simplemente falla tanto en el emulador como en mi teléfono, ya sea al momento de iniciar la cámara o de escanear el código en cuestión.
No se cual pueda ser el problema ya que he probado con varios tutoriales distintos e incluso he usado uno con Google ML Kit que mostraba que estaba creando el proyecto para Android 5.0, también probé con otras versiones de Android más nuevas en los emuladores del Android Studio pero tampoco funciona, y como use distintos tutoriales pero todos fallaban en el mismo punto no se si es un problema de mi Android Studio que puede estar fallando o que parte del código deba mostrar.

¿Qué queda en el log del teléfono? Sobre la parte del código a mostrar, ya que dices que falla siempre en el mismo punto, pues es ese código, en el que se produce el fallo, para comenzar.

No recuerdo haber visto algún error especifico en el log, pero volveré a mirar. El problema como mencione es que falla en todos los códigos de los tutoriales que he encontrado, todos eran distintos y ninguno daba un error de compilación o similar.
